# How to configure a server for internal use only [Ubuntu]

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, iptables

I'm trying to build a VM- Home Lab with different Ubuntu Servers.
I want to make every server not accesible from outsite/internet and I thought I could do this by configuring iptables.

I tried a couple of Tutorials suggesting me to DROP all traffic and set it up to only ACCPET from my internal network (eg. 10.10.0.0/24).

However when I follow these turotials I always end up with a couple of errors:

- First of all, if I start with the command `iptables -P INPUT DROP` I cannot continue with the rest of the commands, because the server somehow cant resolve his own hostname
- When I add my local IP- Range with `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` I cannot access my server from my host machine via ssh or can't even load a webpage hosted on it

My main goal is to make the server accesible from every computer, laptop etc... on in my home network, but not from outside. So my friends and I can work together on coding projects, when they bring their laptop.

Maybe I'm overdoing it, and maybe there's an easier way (Using the virtualbox hypervisor).

The services running on the machines are gitlab-ce and jira on the other.

Any help would be appreciated, since this is my first time working with such things (I'm actually just a software dev :P)

Cheers

Comment: So you are using "bridged networking" mode? Your router is already preventing access to your servers from the internet isn't it?

Comment: Same remark. By default your home modem/router prevents the systems on the Internet to connect to your home machines (in other words it only allows outbound connections).  Also, on Ubuntu you can install `ufw` (Uncomplicated FireWall) which is a lot easier to use than `iptables`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Didn't know that routers already block access...

Comment: That's why you need to set up `port forwarding` on the router if you want to make something accessible from outside. After all, how else is the router supposed to know which device on your home network it should forward a packet to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways to configure your hypervisor to achieve your goal:

1. Each VM has its network adapter *attached to* `bridged adapter`. You then have to configure a public IP (eg. in 10.10.0.0/24) for each of these network adapter.

   Finally your may execute following iptables commands on your host:

   - `iptables -P INPUT DROP` to set your default policy as DROP
   - `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.10.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT` : to allow packet from your internal network.
2. Each VM has its network adapter *attached to* `NAT`. You then have to configure port redirection for each service of each VM (VM Settings > Network > Advanced > Port Forwarding button at bottom). Please see the note at the end of post for more details on port forwarding configuration.

   Then you have to execute the following iptables commands on your host:

   - `iptables -P INPUT DROP`
   - `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.10.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT`
   - instead of the last command you can be more precise in your authorization: `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.10.0.0/24 --dport ssh -j ACCEPT` but you may have to sometimes reconfigure iptables if you add more services to you VMs.

In that case your VMs won't be reachable from the internet and from the rest of internal network, assuming that your whole internal network is 10.0.0.0/8.
**Note**
You will have more details on *bridged/NAT* and *port forwarding* [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/)

**EDIT**

Considering conmments below request, I didn't realized that your local network is 'only' 10.10.0.0/24 (and not 10.0.0.0/8). To top that, 10.10.0.0/24 belong to the wider *private network* 10.0.0.0/8 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), which is not routable on the internet (I mean without VPN, but it's not technically routing). Therefore client from the internet will not be able to reach internal VMs.